# EF core 3 and Migration.BuildTargetModel

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to understand the utility of the `BuildTargetModel` of each migration with the snapshot during runtime.

Each time you add a migration it adds a new `BuildTargetModel` in a designer class of the migration.

I understand this code is useful to generate new migration and being able to come back to the snapshot of any version of the database.

My concern is about the utility of this code for the runtime and when you do not need to switch to previous version but using only the last one.

I remove each `BuildTargetModel` method of all migrations and even the `ModelSnapshot` class. Result is that my code works like a charm.

So any reason to keep the `BuildTargetModel` override method on each Migration for the runtime ?

Comment: If migration has inserts, updates, HasData, etc., applying migration should fail if you remove `BuildTargetModel`.

Comment: You can try to generated idempotent SQL script to ensure that this is true.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv
I have lot of migration with Insert, Updates in the Up method and with or without the BuildTargetModel it works exactly the same.

For my understanding BuildTargetModel is only to have a snapshot of the database on a certain version.

Comment: When I tried to remove Design files in EF Core 6 - idempotent script stopped generation.